# Does Leaflet.js support Edge browser?

Tags: leaflet

[Leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/index.html) 1.0 was released last month. Their website mentions a list of of supported browsers----but doesn't include MS Edge. I surmise that list is out of date, but I wanted to know if Leaflet *officially* supports Edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Leaflet code includes some hacks to make sure Edge behaves as expected with some cases involving touchscreens (see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/63fd4edc76893ab2a2f83d54e703e0a4da73de7b/src/dom/DomEvent.DoubleTap.js#L65 ), so yes, we do pay attention to the Edge browser.